# All adb commands

Tags: android, shell, adb

How can I see the list of **all** commands that ever existed in ADB
For example a `backup` command is not listed on [this page](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) but I use https://web.archive.org/ I can see that once the command was written on the page but today it no longer exists

Is there a place where you can see **all** the commands? Even those which have been removed from the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is adb man page.
You can find that [here](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/adb.1.html) or by also typing in terminal:

```
adb --help
```

Comment: Thank you!
It is very useful. Do you know if there is one for Adb shell as well?

Comment: The command binaries are stored in the file system of the emulator or device, at /system/bin/. So whatever you see in your emulator at /system/bin or /bin you can execute that.

But there are some common commands listed at here: http://android-doc.github.io/tools/help/shell.html